# Mobile navigation not working on divi theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Divi theme in WordPress. I've been working on 2 websites that are similar and both have the same code in header.php (I copied and pasted it).

It works fine on one website and not on the other. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is clearly an error of some description.

Answer (score 1):

You should tell us more details, for example show us links of your pages, or which part of your code you think is the problem. If you copied and pasted it double check the classes and id, is your css same in both websites?